# INotifyPropertyChanged with singelton class

Tags: c#, wpf

i'm trying to implement INotifyPropertyChanged within singelton class.

Here is my code:

> public class plc : INotifyPropertyChanged
>       {
>
> ```
>     private static plc instance;
>     public plc()
>     {
>     }
>
>     public static plc Instance
>     {
>         get
>         {
>             if (instance == null)
>             {
>                 instance = new plc();
>             }
>             return instance;
>         }
>         set
>         {
>             instance = value;
>         }
>     }
>
>
>
>     private static string _plcIp{get; set;}
>     public string plcIp
>     {
>         get
>         {
>             return _plcIp;
>             OnPropertyChanged();
>         }
>         set
>         {
>             _plcIp = value;
>         }
>
>     }
>
>     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
>
>     private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
>     {
>         if (PropertyChanged != null)
>         {
>             PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
>         }
>     }
> ```

I'm getting error unreachable code deleted and of course NotifyPropertyChange isn't working

Comment: Additionally to prevent race conditions your PropertyChanged function should be `var handler = PropertyChanged; if (handler != null) { handler, this....`

Answer (score 3):

It's because you are calling `OnPropertyChanged();` after you `return _plcIp;`.

It should be called after you set the value. i.e.:

```
public string plcIp
{
    get
    {
        return _plcIp;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != _plcIp)
        {
            _plcIp = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

You should also check that the value is actually changing in the setter before raising the event.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues in your code:

- if you are implementing singleton, then constructor of class should be private
- use fields instead of private properties
- properties should not be static (you are using singleton)
- verify if property value really changed before raising OnPropertyChanged event
- raise event before returning property value
- use PascalNames for class name and properties names
- raise event from setter instead of getter

Code:

```
public class Plc : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private static Plc _instance;

    private Plc() { } // constructor should be private

    public static Plc Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)                
                _instance = new Plc();

            return _instance;
        } // you don't need setter
    }  

    private string _plcIp; // instance field instead of static property

    public string PlcIp
    {
        get { return _plcIp; }
        set
        {
            if (_plcIp == value)
                return; // check if value changed

            _plcIp = value; // change value
            OnPropertyChanged(); // raise event               
        }    
    }    
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This contains the error :

```
public string plcIp
    {
        get
        {
            return _plcIp;
            OnPropertyChanged(); //This row..
        }
        set { _plcIp = value; }    
    }
```

It's in the Set method you want the update in the UI, not when you get the value.
Something like this :

```
public string plcIp
{
    get { return _plcIp; }
    set { _plcIp = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }    
}
```